# Unable to load webpack when running phantomJS

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, webpack, phantomjs, karma-runner

I receive the following error after running `npm run test-phantomjs`:

```
WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[1] should be an object.
 - configuration.module.rules[2] should be an object.
```

Here is what my webpack.config.test.js looks like:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const common = require('./webpack.config.common');
const metadata = require('./releaseMetadata');
const reactCssModules =
  require('@infor/babel-plugin-react-css-modules').default;

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            ['es2015', { modules: false }],
            'react',
          ],
          plugins: [
            'transform-object-rest-spread',
            'lodash',
            [reactCssModules, {
              filetypes: {
                '.scss': 'postcss-scss',
              },
            }],
          ],
        },
      },
      common.cssRule,
      common.imgRule,
      common.svgRule,
    ],
  },
  resolve: common.resolve,
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      BUILD_DATE: metadata.BUILD_DATE,
      BAMBOO_BUILD_NUMBER: metadata.BAMBOO_BUILD_NUMBER,
      VERSION: '"test"',
    }),
  ],
};
```

I'm using `"webpack": "^3.8.1"` in my package.json. Does anyone know what's up with this error? Thanks.